# How should i find the sum of a column from a series of time periods under PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm writing a bandwidth monitor to run on my network, and i've gotten to the stage where i have a database full of packet meta-data (host, in/outbound, size, etc) and i need to graph it. My approach is to take a sum of the packet sizes over a 2 minute period and graph that divided by 120 to give the average bit rate for that period, then repeat this for every 2 minute period in 24 hours. At first i implemented this with 720 separate queries like

```
SELECT SUM(size) 
FROM traffic_log_outbound 
WHERE ip=INET '192.168.1.105' 
  AND time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP 'now' - INTERVAL '1402 minute' 
               AND TIMESTAMP 'now' - INTERVAL '1400 minute'
```

but found this to be terribly inefficient, taking about 400 seconds to finish.

A sample from `traffic_log_outbound`. There is also another table with the same structure, `traffic_log_inbound`.

```
bandwidth_monitor=# SELECT * FROM traffic_log_outbound LIMIT 5;
            time            |      ip       | proto | src_port | dst_port | size
----------------------------+---------------+-------+----------+----------+------
 2014-03-01 19:51:26.851858 | 192.168.1.225 |     6 |    49365 |       80 |   40
 2014-03-01 19:51:26.851907 | 192.168.1.225 |     6 |    49365 |       80 |  377
 2014-03-01 19:51:26.851919 | 192.168.1.225 |     6 |    49343 |       80 |   40
 2014-03-01 19:51:26.853556 | 192.168.1.225 |     6 |    55492 |      443 |   40
 2014-03-01 19:51:26.855605 | 192.168.1.225 |     6 |    55492 |      443 |   40
(5 rows)
```

And the structure

```
bandwidth_monitor=# \d+ traffic_log_outbound
                            Table "public.traffic_log_outbound"
  Column  |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 time     | timestamp without time zone |           | plain   |              |
 ip       | inet                        |           | main    |              |
 proto    | integer                     |           | plain   |              |
 src_port | integer                     |           | plain   |              |
 dst_port | integer                     |           | plain   |              |
 size     | integer                     |           | plain   |              |
Check constraints:
    "traffic_log_outbound_ip_check" CHECK (ip << '192.168.1.0/24'::inet)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: Please put your traffic_log_outbound structure and some of its data.

Comment: @Houari Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Have you considered using [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com) or [Cacti](http://graphite.wikidot.com) instead of Postgres?

Comment: @SamChoukri No. I'm really not interested in using a canned solution. If this was impossible to do with postgres i'd just use bandwidthd or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5de27/1)

```
select
    (extract(epoch from time) / 120)::integer,
    sum(size) as size
from test
where
    ip=inet '192.168.1.69'
    and
    time > current_timestamp - interval '24 hours'
group by 1
order by 1
;
   int4   | size 
----------+------
 11613921 |  100
 11614273 |  400
 11614276 |  200
 11614278 |  400
```

Comment: Seems to work great, unfortunately i don't understand why. This should make for a fine learning experience, though.